# simplifying a multi-function in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, random, setinterval

Hey I'm trying to figure out a way I might be able to simplify my code so that I will not have to have 38 of these functions but only have one that can run 38 different id's at separate times. This is a randomized script that tells the id element to land on a specific letter.

```
var randlet = 0;
var timesrun = 0;

function randomizer() {
    randlet = Math.floor(Math.random() * 26);
    timesrun += 1;
    if (master[randlet] == letter[0]) {
        $('#L1').css('background-position', master[randlet]);
        clearInterval(interval);
    } else {
        if (timesrun == 100) {
            master[randlet] = letter[0];
            $('#L1').css('background-position', master[randlet]);
            clearInterval(interval);
        } else {
            $('#L1').css('background-position', master[randlet]);
        }
    }
}

var interval = setInterval(function() {
    randomizer();
}, 10);
```

Comment: Can't you just give the function an argument, which is the ID of the element to run on?

Comment: Keleko, do you know what a function argument is?

Comment: do `function randomizer(id){}` then `randomizer("#myid1");` and so on and so forth

Comment: I see what you guys are meaning, but each Id will have a different value ie id1 = letter[0] and id2 = letter[1]. As well as their own randlet number and timesrun.

Comment: You can use jQuery's `.data()` method to associate data with the element, so each element will have its own values. E.g. `$(this).data("id1")`.

Comment: hmm.. doesn't solve the problem with one clearing the interval and the others have not finished their processes yet.

Answer (score 0):

For each element, set a class called 'randomise'. In the function, use the jquery .each method to iterate over each randomised element. If that element needs to have its value fixed, simp,y remove the 'randomise' class. When no more elements have the randomise class anymore, clear the timer.

Comment: Then you can also get rid of the ids